# FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel-5.1

```
            PaymentController.php 

            <?php 
            namespace App\Http\Controllers;
            use Paypalpayment;
            class paymentController extends Controller 
            {
                private $_apiContext;
                function __construct()
                {
                    $this->_apiContext = Paypalpayment::apiContext(config('paypal_payment.Account.ClientId'
                    ), config('paypal_payment.Account.ClientSecret'));

                }
                public function store()
                {
                    $addr= Paypalpayment::address();
                    $addr->setLine1("3909 Witmer Road");
                    $addr->setLine2("Niagara Falls");
                    $addr->setCity("Niagara Falls");
                    $addr->setState("NY");
                    $addr->setPostalCode("14305");
                    $addr->setCountryCode("US");
                    $addr->setPhone("716-298-1822");
                    $card = Paypalpayment::creditCard();
                    $card->setType("visa")
                        ->setNumber("4758411877817150")
                        ->setExpireMonth("05")
                        ->setExpireYear("2019")
                        ->setCvv2("456")
                        ->setFirstName("Joe")
                        ->setLastName("Shopper");
                    $fi = Paypalpayment::fundingInstrument();
                    $fi->setCreditCard($card);
                    $payer = Paypalpayment::payer();
                    $payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
                        ->setFundingInstruments(array($fi));
                        $item1 = Paypalpayment::item();
                    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
                            ->setDescription('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
                            ->setCurrency('USD')
                            ->setQuantity(1)
                            ->setTax(0.3)
                            ->setPrice(7.50);
                    $item2 = Paypalpayment::item();
                    $item2->setName('Granola bars')
                            ->setDescription('Granola Bars with Peanuts')
                            ->setCurrency('USD')
                            ->setQuantity(5)
                            ->setTax(0.2)
                            ->setPrice(2);
                    $itemList = Paypalpayment::itemList();
                    $itemList->setItems(array($item1,$item2));
                    $details = Paypalpayment::details();
                    $details->setShipping("1.2")
                            ->setTax("1.3")
                            //total of items prices
                            ->setSubtotal("17.5");

                    //Payment Amount
                    $amount = Paypalpayment::amount();
                    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
                            // the total is $17.8 = (16 + 0.6) * 1 ( of quantity) + 1.2 ( of Shipping).
                            ->setTotal("20")
                            ->setDetails($details);


                    $transaction = Paypalpayment::transaction();
                    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                        ->setItemList($itemList)
                        ->setDescription("Payment description")
                        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());



                    $payment = Paypalpayment::payment();

                    $payment->setIntent("sale")
                        ->setPayer($payer)
                        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
                        try
                     {

                       $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
                          }
                     catch (\PPConnectionException $ex) 
                     {
                        return  "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    dd($payment);
                } 
            }

            ?>

        Composer.json 
        {
            "name": "laravel/laravel",
            "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
            "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
            "license": "MIT",
            "type": "project",
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.5.9",
                "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
                 "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
               "anouar/paypalpayment" : "~1.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
                "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
                "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
            },


        FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
        i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found


        FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
        i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
    FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
        i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
        i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
    FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
        i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
```

FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
            i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
        FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
            i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found
 i m getting this error FatalErrorException: Class 'anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Can you find it yourself on disk?

Comment: ta.speot.is  what are u asking me...i m not able to understand ...on disk?

Answer (score 0):

PHP namespaces are case-sensitive. It seems like you made a mistake in the `config/app.php` file when defining the Service Provider for the Paypalpayment package.

It should be:

```
Anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider::class
```

instead of:

```
anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider::class
```